# My postman assertion script, give me an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')"

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

My postman assertion script gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')".
My script is as follows:

pm.expect(jsonData.transaction_details[0].references.customer_message_identifier).to.be.null;

And my response is as follows:

{
"customer_message_identifier": null,
}

Comment: Your response is not valid JSON, lets start there.

Comment: It's a valid JSON, i just forgot to include the {.....}. I just wanted to show the exact response that's NULL, and why i'm getting the error.

Comment: I have solved it. It was another test in the group that had an invalid property.

Answer (score 0):

Another test in the group had an invalid property.